# How to registerType with a PARAMETER constructor?

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container

How do I registertype with the container where the type doesn't have NO PARAMETER constructor.

In fact my constructor accepts a string, and I normally pass in a string that represents a Path.

So when I do resolve it automatically creates the new type but passing in a string?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It's simple. When you register the constructor, you just pass the value you want injected for the parameter. The container matches up your constructor based on the type of value (API) or name of parameter (XML).

In the API, you'd do:

```
container.RegisterType<MyType>(new InjectionConstructor("My string here"));
```

That will select a constructor that takes a single string, and at resolve time will pass the string "My string here".

The equivalent XML (using the 2.0 config schema) would be:

```
<register type="MyType">
  <constructor>
    <param name="whateverParameterNameIs" value="My string here" />
  </constructor>
</register>
```

Comment: What if i want multiple istance with different strings?

Comment: Create two named registrations, with your two different strings, then resolve with the desired name for the particular use case. If you want something more complex, you're probably using a container incorrectly.

Answer (score 19):

You can also use the built in InjectionConstructor and ResolvedParameter where connectionString is the database connection string to be used.

```
// install a named string that holds the connection string to use
container.RegisterInstance<string>("MyConnectionString", connectionString, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()); 

// register the class that will use the connection string
container.RegisterType<MyNamespace.MyObjectContext, MyNamespace.MyObjectContext>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<string>("MyConnectionString")));

var context = container.Resolve<MyNamespace.MyObjectContext>();
```

You could take it even one step further and have multiple named instances of MyObjectContext, each using their own connection string to different databases.

Comment: new ResolvedParameter<string>("MyConnectionString") but got an error The type String cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value,

Answer (score 0):

Over 13 years later I'm looking for an answer to this same question.

I discovered how to do it from the [quickstart doc at UnityContainer.org](http://unitycontainer.org/articles/quickstart.html).

All of the old answers to this provide a solution that uses the `InjectionConstructor` but here in 2024 I wasn't finding that.

**Just Like OP**

Just like the OP I have a class that needs a Path passed in as a string to construct it.

I'll keep my sample very small.  Here's the Interface:

```
public interface ITrackable
{
    // StorageTarget is one of the following:
    // 1. full-filename (including path)
    // 2. DB Connection string
    // 3. URI to location where data will be posted.
    String StorageTarget { get; }
    bool WriteActivity(String message);
}
```

Here's the smallest snippet of the implementation class:

```
public class FileActivityTracker : ITrackable
{
    private String FileName;
    
    public FileActivityTracker(String fileName)
    {
        FileName = fileName;
    }
    
    public string StorageTarget
    {
        get
        {
            return FileName;
        }
    }
    ...
```

**Register & Resolve**

I needed to `Register` my type with Unity and then have it construct one (via `Resolve`).

The code *built* with no problems.
Once the code *ran* the `Register` method succeeded with no problem.
However, when the code hit the `Resolve` call then the app would crash with the following :

**Somewhat Confusing Error**

> {"Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "FileActivityTracker",
> name = "(none)".\r\nException occurred while: while
> resolving.\r\nException is: InvalidOperationException - **The type
> String cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to
> supply this
> value.**\r\n-----------------------------------------------\r\nAt the
> time of the exception, the container was:\r\n\r\n  Resolving
> FileActivityTracker,(none)\r\n  Resolving parameter "config" of
> constructor
> FileActivityTracker(\r\n    Resolving (none)\r\n    Resolving parameter
> "**fileName**" of constructor **FileActivityTracker(System.String
> fileName)**\r\n      Resolving System.String,(none)\r\n"}

**Solution**

The docs at UnityContainer.org show an example and state that you need to register the string instance that will be passed into the constructor.

I simply added that call before my call to the `Resolve` method and it works perfectly now (first line, shown in following example).

```
// Register string instance
container.RegisterInstance(@"c:\user\user.name\myfile.log");
container.Resolve<FileActivityTracker();
```

BTW, you can step into the code when the `Resolve` method is called and you can see your constructor code being executed.

**One Last Thing**

I'm not sure how it picks that particular string to use as the input to my constructor.  Maybe it is because I register the string on the line before I make the call to `Resolve`, but I'm not sure.
I would think there would be a way to specify which registered string will be used for various constructors that you may have which require a string.  Discovering that will take more reading of the docs I suppose.